# Is cheesemaking ontopic?

Tags: discussion

I am a homebrewer; I often make wine and I'll be asking more questions about wine in the future. Recently I took up cheesemaking. Is that also on topic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the sake of having an answer that reflects the comments:

Cheesemaking is off-topic, and fits better in 'Seasoned Advice' than in homebrewing. [The on-topic document](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) over there lists `Cooking & food preparation methods` are on topic, and I think we can agree cheese falls under food preparation.

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts would be cheese making is off topic as it is hard to drink cheese.

Comment: Is "needs to be drinkable" a requirement?

Comment: I would think for a homebrewing community yes being drinkable would be a delimiter, as this is generally thought to refer to home brewed cider/beer/wine, kombucha and kefir and ginger beer come up occasionally. Happy for other to disagree but I think this SE is here for people to discuss and learn about the process and craft around fermented drinks.

Comment: Counter to my comment above I can't find anywhere else that makes any sense for cheese making to sit in the world of StackExchange. Do we open this up and accept all homebrewed fermented food and drinks stuffs, or are we drinkable fermentations only?

Comment: I think cheesemaking would be on-topic on the cooking site ("seasoned advice")? Arguably, quite a few questions on this site could be considered on-topic on the cooking site. Personally, I think it's more useful to approach this from a *community* standpoint than from a *what is on-topic* standpoint, though (see [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/14/unix-and-ubuntu-why-both/)).

Comment: @carpetsmoker, you are 100% correct having had a quick look over there 'Seasoned Advice' is the right place for cheese making to live.

Comment: Might be a good way to rephrase https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic a bit and add "beverages" somewhere.

Comment: I will take a look at rephrasing and expanding to clarify on topic/off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The progression from wine making to cheese makes sense with their common pairing and is actually a topic of conversation between my girlfriend and I after brewing our first batch of wine.

To address the question, I would agree with the previous answers as brewing is understood (at the very least colloquially) as a method of producing beverage. I would like to add however that with increasing scientific focus around the gut microbiome, interest in fermented foods such as sauerkraut, kimchi, sourdough bread, etc has also appeared to have increased. Proposing a category for fermented foods as a topic may generate worthwhile discussion that addresses safety, recipes, scientific research and more!